# git pull gives me this error: "may be you are offiline or behind a proxy check your internet connection and proxy configuration"

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I am trying to pull the project from git hub. one of my project gives me the following error.

> "may be you are offiline or behind a proxy check your internet connection and proxy configuration"  Download cancelled.

I have tried from git gui and eclipse. I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

My other projects have no problem in pulling or pushing and This particular project I used to pull everyday and now it gives error.

My Internet Connection is working properly and I am able to clone and pull my other project same time.

Anybody could figure out, What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Can you check which protocol each project uses? (ssh://, git://, http(s)://) – maybe this one uses a different one

Comment: yes, this is the most possible cause for this error. All should be interchangeable.

Comment: Hi friends My configuration was correct. The reason was I have a slow internet connection and the pull was bigger in size. It was containing images and sound files. So other project's pull worked as the data is in kbs. And this particular project was giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed when i pulled it from the terminal. I have used git pull command.  Is there any better answer?